# How to replace a word found in a string with what is in the list in Python

Tags: python, list

My string is below:

```
word = "Continue: Lifetime Benefits in Running, Volume 1, Issue 1, February 2018"
```

My list is:

```
italic_list = ['Continue', ': Lifetime Benefits in Running', ' February 2018']
```

I want to change the found word(s) in the string with what's in the list with an additional tag .

The output should be like this:

```
<p>
    <italic>Continue: Lifetime Benefits in Running</italic>, Volume 1, Issue 1, <italic>February 2018</italic>
</p>
```

Here is my code:

```
word = "Continue: Lifetime Benefits in Running, Volume 1, Issue 1, February 2018"

italic_list = ['Continue', ': Lifetime Benefits in Running', ' February 2018']

ital = ''.join(italic_list)

if ital in word:
    word = word.replace(ital, "<italic>" + ital + "</italic>")
```

The code will work if all items in the list are in a succeeding words.  But the problem with this code is if there is a certain word not in succeeding with the previous item(s).

I hope there is a better way to solve this.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

**Don't join.**

It merge list elements into single string. You had 3 phrases that could be independently checked. Now you have single string.

Instead what you want to do, is to check if any of phrases from italic_list are present in input string *one by one*.

In python you can do that with loops. Just loop over italic_list, and for each element check if element is present in input string, and if so, replace that part with one with extra elements.